# Hyper-V Enhanced Session Mode Does Not Work

Tags: server, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I am new to virtual machines so pardon my ignorance.

I have a host machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I'm trying to run a VM with Windows 8.1 Enterprise using Hyper-V. I need to be able to use USB devices on the VM.

Please check screenshot for the Hyper-V settings and the VM settings. The VMConnect does not have 'Show Options' to select local resources.

I tried using Remote Desktop Connection to the VM but nothing happens when USB devices are plugged in the host machine.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Any help in fixing this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Hyper-V Settings
[image: Screenshot 1: Hyper-V Settings]

VM Settings
[image: Screenshot 2: VM Settings]

Answer (score 1):

If the USB device you want to use in the VM is a USB memory stick share it with the RDP local resources option as a **Drive** instead of the trying to replicate the USB port itself.

Eg:

[image]

Comment: It's not a USB memory stick so I can't select it as a drive. Does port replication not work?

Comment: @VigneshSubramaniam I don't think so. Check out this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282274(v=ws.11).aspx It basically says the same thing. I'm fairly sure you can do it with Virtual Box though.

Comment: Yes Virtual Box can do it... http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/120509.aspx

Comment: There are 'USB devices' and 'Plug and Play devices' in the local resources list. 

I'll give Virtual Box a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a dependency(XRDP) to be installed in order to enable Enhanced Session Mode. Please follow the following steps or watch this video for more clarity.

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS2m6iyG7_M&ab_channel=VikeshYadav

On hyper-v linux machine:

1. git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools
2. cd linux-vm-tools/ubuntu/18.04/
3. sudo chmod +x install.sh
4. sudo ./install.sh

On windows machine:

1. set-vm -VMName ubuntu -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket

Answer (score 0):

I've got Win8.1 guest system (1 gen VM) and Win10 as host. Tried pretty much everything, but wasn't able to enable Enhanced Mode (simply grayed out all the time), unless I enabled RDP connections in the guest system (Control Panel, Allow remote access to your computer). After this change VMConnect with ability to share local resources appeared on attempt to connect to the VM.

Hope this helps all the people who find this thread while googling.